# How do I traverse through a deeply nested JSON if it has an indefinite nesting in java?

Tags: java, json

For example I have the following JSON:

```
{

        "field1": "value1",
        "field2: "value2",
        "array1" : [
                "field1": "value1",
                "field2: "value2",
                "array1" : [
                    "field1": "value1",
                    "field2: "value2",
                 ]
        ]

}
```

it could have more or nesting inside with the same format, how do I traverse through it using recursion?,

OK, it seems I made a bit of confusion, the json could be the one above or like this one below in increasing "nests" like that russian doll:

```
{

        "field1": "value1",
        "field2: "value2",
        "array1" : [
                "field1": "value1",
                "field2: "value2",
                "array1" : [
                    "field1": "value1",
                    "field2: "value2",
                        "array1" : [
                            "field1": "value1",
                            "field2: "value2",
                     ]
                 ]
        ]

}
```

Comment: Which json library are you using? Most have a method to check if a value is an object or array

Comment: Hi Cricket, I am using org json for the library.

Comment: When you say infinite , what do you really mean? does it not end at all? OR is it a growing json? If your problem deals with growing json, then, the perspective of looking at "Iteration over json" is incorrect in my opinion, you better make use of Stream apis instead

Comment: @forkdbloke, it ends, what I meant was the json to be processed could have random number of "nesting", depending on the data sent to me.

Comment: So, in that case, i would suggest go for JSONPath(as suggested in Approach#1 in my answer), as you need to have random access on a structured json with unknown elements, and still, you would be able to iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use Jackson or Gson, you could define a POJO, which you can parse and iterate through like any other object

```
public class Foo {
    String field1, field2;
    List<Foo> array1;

    public static void traverse(Foo f) {
        if (f.array1 == null) return;
        // do something for current object 
        for (Foo next : f.array1) traverse(next);
        // do something after visiting all children 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**APPROACH#0**

Convert JSON to POJO and make use of [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library, and you can iterate any object from POJO.

**APPROACH#1**

Please do not re-invent the wheel, as there are many libraries which has been created and improved overtime by many contributors.

Please make use of [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

You can access a complex json like below, by making use of the code below,

You can traverse the below list using iterator.

```
// get first author 
String author0 = JsonPath.read(document, "$.store.book[0].author");

// get all titles 
List<String> titles = JsonPath.parse(JSON_DOCUMENT).read("$.store.book[*].title", typeRef);
```

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

Comment: How does that help access infinitely deep arrays? You'd need to know the index at each point

Comment: When you say infinite , what do you really mean? does it not end at all? OR is it a growing json?

Comment: I'm not sure. Read the question... "it could have more or nesting inside with the same format"

Comment: If your problem deals with growing json, then, the perspective of looking at "Iteration over json" is incorrect in my opinion, you better make use of Stream apis instead.

Comment: AFAIK, the streams api doesn't recurse nested objects. They'd have to be flattened to a single iterable

Comment: in that case , one can create POJO for the respective JSON and make use of gson library.

Comment: Jsonpath deep-scan should work, but it would still return all nested results